# Have I been hacked? If not what is happening?

Tags: firefox, suspend, security, libreoffice, rhythmbox

I was on google looking at phones the other night, I closed the windows and my laptop's lid then went to bed. When I got back today at about 4 pm the guest account was open and many windows such as firefox, a spreadsheet (blank), Ubuntu software center, and the settings for the appearance. Prior to this I was logged into my account and had never even opened the guest account. No one in my house has been on my computer. Fearing the worst I started Dban but I am wondering what happened.

**Update:** I have reinstalled Ubuntu on it and I closed the laptop lid for about an hour WHILE I WAS IN THE ROOM. No one else entered and now Rhythmbox, Videos, Firefox, computer information libreoffice and my file manager have been opened. Additionally 4 untitled folders have been created on my desktop. I am very concerned now as this is after Dban and I haven't connected to wifi!

Update: All this is happening within a guest session

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54354/discussion-on-question-by-blue-dabba-dee-have-i-been-hacked-if-not-what-is-happ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not hacked based on the information in your question and comments dialog.

- **It only happens when you close the lid**: This indicates some correlations to closing some interference or keys being stuck when closing the lid as a trigger.
- **Guest account access**: I don't think it's possible for remote access to create a Guest account login.
- **GUI Access**: If someone really had access to hack into your system, it's almost totally unlikely they would do it via a Guest GUI that you could watch.  They would do it through some more covert method.  If they needed GUI, they would send it to their screen, not to yours.
- **Criterion for Remote Desktop**: Based on your description of this happening on a brand new default installation, the Remove Desktop wouldn't be activated by default.  You would have to manually activate it.
- **Public IP access**: Even if you activated the remote desktop feature, since most networks have a router for networking, a person couldn't connect to your remote desktop port without a manual port forwarding configuration of your router.

Comment: Serg... you and I were making the same edit at the same time.   Uncanning!